# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.CookieTei

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

i am finding java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.CookieTei.

i have already struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar, struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar on my classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have some dependencies on struts-1. [jarfinder finds this class only in struts-1 libs](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.CookieTei). Get rid of all struts-1 jars, and place only struts-2 jars in your classpath.